# Unable to parseFloat a string with double apix

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use parseFloat function to get float value from a string, the string is returned from an API call and it's value looks like this `"1.1"`

But when i'm casting the `parseFloat(string)` it returns NaN..

Here is my code:

```
    const response = await httpGet(); // response here returns "1.1"
    let importo = parseFloat(response.toString()); // return NaN
    console.log(importo)
```

Here is the httpGet:

```
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
        host: 'www.example.cloud',
        port: 443,
        path: '/api/alexa',
        method: 'GET',
    };
    
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      let returnData = '';
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        console.log(returnData)
        resolve(returnData);
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
```

And here is a console log of the value and the importo

[image]

I'm using Alexa Developer Console to do so...

Comment: Try casting response to String and then parse it. ``` let importo = parseFloat(String(response)); ```

Comment: @S.Ramjit i've yet tryed to do response.toString()

Comment: Turns out you don't have to convert to string. `parseFloat()` converts it to string and then parses it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#Parameters make sure you don't have any trailing whitespaces in `response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was able to solve the issue only by passing from my API an object instead of a simple return of the string as in any case i was unable to use parseFloat.

Then by returning an object with the correct data type (float) all works as it have to without any need of use of parseFloat.